# Facebook thinks this site may be unsafe but my website is safe

Tags: facebook

Whenever anybody clicks on a link that I've posted on any Facebook Page (including my page https://www.facebook.com/ompeespace) to my website (http://www.ompeespace.com) they get directed to a warning message which reads:

> Facebook thinks this site may be unsafe. If you're not familiar with it, please provide feedback by marking it as spam (you'll be brought back to Facebook)

Any idea why this is happening? Μy site is safe and not a spam site! I've checked with Google Webmaster tools - no issues or malware. I tried to contact facebook to resolve this issue but no response.